# Why doesn't Electronics show up in the dropdown?

Tags: support, top-bar

I wanted to ask a question about travel electronics. I used the sites dropdown to see if there was an electronics site, and got this result:

[image]

OK, no electronics site, I'll ask on Travel. But it turns out there is [an electronics site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Why didn't it appear?

Comment: Wait, what? (Checks URL) ok, so that is not an electronics site is it? I mean not for asking about clocks and displays from a store. Maybe about building your own...

Answer (score 7):

Electrical Engineering *is* the Electronics Stack Exchange site.

It's URL is:

> https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

which is what you've linked to in the question.

So... it did appear! :)

You're probably confused because of the name change that [happened a few years ago](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/565):

> We're planning on using the title 'Electrical Engineering'. Everything else, including the URL, will remain the same. This is change in title only.

---

It's [on-topic page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site is for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts. We ask and answer questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics, which include electronics, physical computing, and those working with microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems. We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent datasheets or some source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific electronics design problem
> - the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
> - a communication scheme
> - the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
> - consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses
> - Programming software for a PC
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: ok, pretty clear my question is off topic there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Electrical Engineering and Electronics are the same site. Electrical Engineering has the domain electronics.stackexchange.com. So it did show up.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)